# How to bind text size to slider in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Hi I am trying to display a Text object and a slider that controls the font size of the text.
using the JavaFX property value to observe the slider value change and then update the text size based on slider value. Am I missing something?

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class TextSlider extends VBox
{
    private Text text;
    private Slider slider;
    private VBox vbox;
    private Font font;
    private double initVal = 20;
    public TextSlider()
    {
        text = new Text("Amsterdam");
        slider = new Slider(0,150,100);
        text.setFont(new Font(initVal));
       // slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        //slider.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        //text.fontProperty();
        text.textProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
        vbox = new VBox(text,slider);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this with property bindings directly, but you could register a change listener to the slider value property and in the listener update the size of the font of the text.

Comment: what do you expect to happen if you bind the text's _textProperty_ to the slider's _valueProperty_ (which in this case is a number)? Use proper typing and the compiler would have told you that's not possible (wondering how this doesn't blow ... )

Comment: *hach .. it  that doesn't even compile ;)

Comment: @Puce _I'm not sure if you can do this with property bindings_ not if the OP really wants to change the text's font size (Font is immutable)

Comment: Even if the typing and compilation issues are fixed, this won’t actually do anything because there are structural issues with the code. You have a `VBox` subclass, but you never change any of the state of the current `VBox` instance. Instead, you create a new `VBox` and add content to it, but you never make that new `VBox` accessible. You need to decide if you’re using inheritance (not recommended) or some kind of creational pattern (recommended), stick to one, and implement it correctly.

Comment: @keeopatra right I realize I did this line wrong it should be                  just///////////////////////////                                  getChildren().addAll(vbox);

Comment: @Puce thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind the font size directly. But you can use `text.styleProperty()`. The style property enables you to change the appearance through css like styles. And you can even bind it to other properties.

```
textNode.styleProperty().bind(
    Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", slider.valueProperty().asString()));
```

This will update the style property of the text node every time the value property of the slider changes. If the slider value changes to 20 the style will be set to `-fx-font-size: 20`.

Another option would be to use a change listener and set a new font on the changed event:

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

      @Override
      public void changed(
         ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, 
         Number oldValue, 
         Number newValue) { 
            text.setFont(new Font(newValue.doubleValue()));
      }
});
```

Java 8+:(Same code as above)

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener(
        (observableValue, oldValue, newValue) ->
                text.setFont(new Font(newValue.doubleValue()))
);
```

Comment: You could also do `text.fontProperty().bind(...)` with an appropriate custom binding. But note that none of these will appear to work without also addressing the structural issues in the OP’s code. (VBox subclass that also contains an inaccessible VBox, etc.)

Comment: @James_D Shure but binding fontProperty seems more complicated to me. The above was what I found most useful when I didn't knew much about bindings. Thanks for pointing out the structural issues in the OP's code. At least this answer may help other people that are searching for binding font size.

Comment: thanks @Matt I would like to learn what the lamba is really doing but other than bucky's fx tutorial on youtube I havent been able to understand them. In my book I have seen what you done in the anonymous inner class is cool too, I have modified it to use a separate class except im still a bit confused on this subject

Comment: @Matt  slider.valueProperty().addListener(this::changed);                                                
                                                                           //       //                                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
{
 text.setFont(new Font(newValue.doubleValue()));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Note that the structure of the code in the question is broken. You have the `TextSlider` class as a subclass of `VBox`, but no elements are ever added to the `TextSlider` instance. Instead, you create a new `VBox` and add content to it; however, since there's no way to access that new `VBox`, there's no way to use your `TextSlider` class to actually see any content.

Other answers have shown other ways to bind the font size to the slider; imo the most direct way to do this is to bind the text's `fontProperty()` using a custom binding. This looks like:

```
text.fontProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> Font.font(slider.getValue()),
    slider.valueProperty()
));
```

Here is a working `TextSlider` class using this binding:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class TextSlider {

    private Text text;
    private Slider slider;
    private VBox vbox;
    private double initVal = 20;
    public TextSlider(String text) {
        this.text = new Text(text);
        slider = new Slider(0,150,initVal);

       // slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        //slider.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        this.text.fontProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
            () -> Font.font(slider.getValue()),
            slider.valueProperty()
        ));        

        vbox = new VBox(this.text,slider);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public Node asNode() {
        return vbox ;
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text.textProperty();
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public DoubleProperty fontSizeProperty() {
        return slider.valueProperty();
    }

    public final double getFontSize() {
        return fontSizeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFontSize(double fontSize) {
        fontSizeProperty().set(fontSize);
    }
}
```

And a typical use case would look like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextSlider textSlider = new TextSlider("Amsterdam");
        root.setTop(textSlider.asNode());
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

from 19+

```java
slider.styleProperty().bind(fontProperty().map(f -> "-fx-font-size: " + f.getSize()));
```